# c++ Std::accumulate for unordered map

Tags: c++, dictionary, lambda, accumulate

I have a function which should accumulate all the values in an unordered map:

```
int sum_val(std::unordered_map<char, int> vm){
    auto addition = [](int a, std::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator b){ return a + b->second; };
    return std::accumulate(vm.begin(), vm.end(), 0, addition);
}
```

However, when I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
 error: 
      no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at markov_gen.cpp:11:21)'
        __init = __binary_op(__init, *__first);

markov_gen.cpp:11:21: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'std::__1::__hash_map_iterator<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<char, int>, void *>
      *> >::value_type' (aka 'pair<const char, int>') to 'std::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator' (aka
      '__hash_map_iterator<__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<char, int>, void *> *> >') for 2nd
      argument
    auto addition = [](int a, ITER b){ return a + b->second; };
```

I'm a little confused why this binary operator `addition` won't work. `vm.begin()` returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the unordered map and is therefore of type `std::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator`, and since the output of my accumulation should be an `int`, the left element in the lambda should always be an `int` while the right element should be the iterator as `std::accumulate` iterates through every key in the unordered map. Therefore, the operation of `int + std::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator` is well defined by my anonymous function. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have passed "dereferenced" iterator type.

```cpp
int sum_val(std::unordered_map<char, int>& vm){
    auto addition = 
    [](int a, const std::pair<const char,int>&  b)
    { return a + b.second; };
    return std::accumulate(vm.begin(), vm.end(), 0, addition);
}
```

@rjc810 you were looking in the wrong place imho:
`The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following: Ret fun(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);` [accumulate doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).
True, it also states "The signature does not need to have const &.", which means "you may freely pass by value if it's cheap".
But as long as key's constness is ensured (i.e. it's `pair<const char, int>`, any reference should do).

As for `How can I confirm that the "dereferenced" iterator type is a const pair`: it's just considered a good practice to pass by const reference if the argument is not going to be modified. But accumulate's spec is pretty explicit about it.

As for pair: [unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), see code examples (but truth be told, it could be more explicit about it).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just examined the docs for `std::pair` and `std::iterator` and it doesn't seem like either document references the other. How can I confirm that the "dereferenced" iterator type is a `const pair` or read more about how these two types are related?

Also, where does the `const` part come from again?

Comment: @rjc810 I've edited my post to explain more, have a look please.

Comment: You should check `std::unordered_map` docs, see `value_type` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: @DanielGouvêa right, I missed the constness of the key... Fixed, thanks!